# UnicodeDecodeError when importing simplejson in Python

Tags: python

I have a program that does nothing but just importing simplejson, and I am getting the UnicodeDecodeError. I am using Python 3.4 (Anaconda). Could you please help me figure out why?

```
import simplejson as json
print ("It cannot reach here.")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from .scanner import JSONDecodeError
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 10, in <module>
    c_make_scanner = _import_c_make_scanner()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 6, in _import_c_make_scanner
    from simplejson._speedups import make_scanner
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

Comment: After you import simplejson, can you run this? `simplejson.__file__` 

I just installed Python3.4 on my Mac and retrieved simplejson with pip, then ran your print command, and had no problem.

Comment: @tandy, the print has nothing to do with it, the error happens on importing

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/238

Comment: Yes. I added the print to just make it more clear the problem is with importing. maybe it actually becomes more confusing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. So it seems simplejson doesn't work with Anaconda?

Comment: @SeaNeedle, yes it seems to be looking at that  issue.

Comment: So is the _speedups.so file corrupt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotly killed my python install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751216/plotly-killed-my-python-install)