# Plotly killed my python install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, plotly

I just tried to install Plotly using pip. I am running python from Anaconda and now anytime I attempt to run anything python I get the following errors and I have no idea how to fix it. I am running on Windows 7 64bit, Python3,4

```
    PS Z:\> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 77, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from .scanner import JSONDecodeError
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 10, in <module>
    c_make_scanner = _import_c_make_scanner()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 6, in _import_c_make_scanner
    from simplejson._speedups import make_scanner
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 4: invalid start byte
PS Z:\>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interaction between Anaconda's version of pip and the latest version of simplejson (which was installed when you installed Plotly).

As a workaround,

```
del C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson
```

This will allow pip and Plotly to work again.  Unfortunately if you ever upgrade Plotly this problem will happen again, so we will add a workaround to the Plotly requirements.txt file that prevents this from happening in future.  (Plotly only actually needs simplejson on Python 2.6 systems.)

There was an Anaconda issue open related to this that I've commented on: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/238

Plotly Python API issue re: finding a workaround so this doesn't happen again (or to other users): https://github.com/plotly/python-api/issues/197

Answer (score 1):

As of version `1.6.10` for the `plotly` package, the `simplejson` and `ordereddict` packages are no longer dependencies.

### TL;DR:

Python 2.6 should use:

```
pip install plotly[PY2.6]
```

While Python 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4 should still use:

```
pip install plotly
```

### More Info:

If you're already hitting the issue in this post, you'll likely need to remove the `simplejson` package as discussed in answer scjody gave.

The `simplejson` and `ordereddict` packages were there to have common dependencies for Python 2.6 through Python 3.4. However, since `simplejson` clashes with anaconda, we now have an "extras" option for the pip install.

As usual, because the version of IPython we depend on doesn't support Python 2.6, there are still two *optional requirements* files which install `matplotlib`, `IPython[notebook]`, etc.

```
optional_requirements.txt
optional_requirements-2-6.txt
```

### Quotes Notes:

Depending on the shell you're using, you may need to wrap the install target in quotes (`''`) when using the extras for Python 2.6:

```
pip install 'plotly[PY2.6]'
```